# Why showing a error messag 'system.ExtrinsicFailed' while calling a Smart Contract function?

Tags: substrate, rust-ink

I've learned how to deploy a contract by following pages:
https://substrate.dev/substrate-contracts-workshop/#/0/deploying-your-contract
https://substrate.dev/docs/en/contracts/deploying-a-contract

But they both fails at the step 'Calling a contract'

Here is the chain source code that I created (referred from https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/creating-your-first-substrate-chain) :
https://github.com/coolcode/sux-contract-chain

Error message:
system.ExtrinsicFailed
extrinsic event

Comment: We need to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

The contact was turning into `tombstone` immediately after creation. This can be prevented when rasing the default `endowment` at deployment.

The tutorial seems to be updated now and at the step when deploying the smart contract (https://substrate.dev/substrate-contracts-workshop/#/0/deploying-your-contract) it contains:

> To instantiate our contract we just need to give this contract account
>   an **endowment** of 10,000,000 and again set the maximum gas allowed to
>   500,000 units.

However, They are considering enhancing the user experience for the contracts that turns into `tombstone`.You can see the discussion here:
https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/304

Answer (score 0):

system.ExtrinsicFailed means something went wrong. [You should decode exactly what went wrong here,](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/extrinsics/decode) then repost if you're still confused. There doesn't seem to be much guidance on what these errors mean so It's confusing ;{ [I'm having my own confusions over here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67841246/substrate-dusty-network-reatetypecall-findmetacall-unable-to-find-call)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. The solution is to set the amount of transfer to be larger.